# How can I get this toggled drop down menu to be open by default - rather than having to have someone click it to initialize it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is where I got my template from: http://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html

How can the CSS be changed such that the menu is open by default? I've tried adding

```
display: visible; !important
```

to all the lines that are relevant to both, or either - the toggle button itself, or the menu itself - but none seem to help.

Comment: Always post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please.

Comment: Are you talking about the menu that is displayed when clicking the black/blue "Dropdown" button?

Comment: You just need to fire trigger click on document ready.. i have add ans for trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `display: visible; !important` is invalid. There is no `visible` value of property `display`. Also, `!important` declarations are written before the semicolon, not after.

If you are trying to achieve this using CSS:

### CSS:

```
.cd-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

You can also modify the HTML:

### HTML:

```
<a class="cd-dropdown-trigger dropdown-is-active"></a>
<nav class="cd-dropdown dropdown-is-active"></nav>
```

Or with jQuery

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').click();
});
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Btw, the CSS answer will always open the dropdown. So the toggle will not working anymore. :)

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for correcting me too. I'm still new to this, but every bit helps.

Comment: @user2928789 No problem. And don't worry just because you're inexperienced. We all were newbies once. Anyways, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think adding class `.dropdown-is-active` to both `.cd-dropdown-trigger` and `.cd-dropdown` will working. Example:

```
<a class="cd-dropdown-trigger dropdown-is-active"></a>
<nav class="cd-dropdown dropdown-is-active"></nav>
```

Or you can use jQuery to trigger click on `.cd-dropdown-trigger` when document is ready. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to **trigger click** event of document ready

```
<a class="cd-dropdown-trigger" href="#0">Dropdown</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.cd-dropdown').addClass('dropdown-is-active'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class *"dropdown-is-active"* to the nav and the a element

This class is added with jQuery when jou click the button.

Best way is to use jQuery to start with adding the class and not hardcode in your html file

```
$('.cd-dropdown').addClass('dropdown-active');
$('.cd-dropdown-trigger').addClass('dropdown-active');
```

Best way is to use the jQuery toggle method.